# Why does my tag search update/refresh?

Tags: support, tags, search

[payment-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payment-gateway) is one of my "favorite tags", but I've noticed that if I click on it, I get one set of results displayed momentarily, before a refresh changes the results and some questions are removed.

For example - [When is a payment successful in Stripe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43763529/when-is-a-payment-successful-in-stripe) appears temporarily and then disappears.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag (as well as [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)) to your *ignored* tags list, and you have the *Hide questions in your ignored tags* option selected. The *payment successful in Strip* question is tagged with `php`, so it is hidden as you requested.

Hiding posts with ignored tags is done in the browser, so they first load, then are hidden.

If you want to keep seeing these posts, either remove [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) from your ignored tags list, or go to your [preferences page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#tag-subscriptions) and switch the radio option under *Tags* to *Gray out questions in your ignored tags*. Posts with ignored tags are then not removed, just shown in a faded fashion:

> [image: grayed out stripe question]

Comment: Doh, of course!